# How to import module that contains a file in it

Tags: python, module

I have installed a custom module I created myself for learning. If I do

```
from my_first_module import test
test.thisprintssomething()
```

The function will work, but if I do

```
import my_first_module
test.thisprintssomething()
```

Python spits out, NameError: name 'test' is not defined. How would I import without using "from"?

EDIT:

I've fixed it myself. I forgot to add an "import test" line to my **init**.py in my_first_module module.

Answer (score 6):

since you are importing `my_first_module`
you have to tell the code,, `test` belongs to `my_first_module`

```
import my_first_module

my_first_module.test.thisprintssomething()
```

for more clarification you can have a look at [Importing Python Modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)

Comment: I get this error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test', when I try doing that.

Answer (score 3):

```
import my_first_module

my_first_module.test.thisprintssomething()
```

This will work. Read more at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html